# C# - Xamarin.Forms Firebase Storage, get image and display image in binding

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms with Firebase Storage, I have a database with users, each user has `imagePath` each `imagePath` is the file name stored in Firebase Storage. What I am trying to do is get the full image path so I can display my image for each user.

I have this class:

public class UsersClass
{

```
    FirebaseStorageHelper firebaseStorageHelper = new FirebaseStorageHelper();

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string imagePath { get; set; }
    public Task<string> image
    {

        get
        {
            return GetImage(imagePath);
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> GetImage(string image)
    {
        return await firebaseStorageHelper.GetFile(image);
    }
}
```

and I have created this class to handle all my firebase stuff (uploading and downloading)

public class FirebaseStorageHelper
{

```
    public async Task<string> UploadFile(Stream fileStream, string fileName)
    {
        FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = new FirebaseStorage("xxx-xxx.appspot.com");
        var imageUrl = await firebaseStorage.Child("AppName").Child(fileName).PutAsync(fileStream);
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetFile(string fileName)
    {
        FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = new FirebaseStorage("xxx-xxx.appspot.com");
        return await firebaseStorage
            .Child("AppName")
            .Child(fileName)
            .GetDownloadUrlAsync();
    }
}
```

And I am getting my class of Users populated like so in my xaml.cs file:

```
List<UsersClass> users = await webService.GetUsers();

Users.ItemsSource = kids;
```

And using a collection view to display each user, but for the image I get a blank image, everything else is displaying except the image:

```
<Image Source="{Binding image}" />
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get each users image to display?

Comment: your image property returns a Task, not a string, the Image control can't handle that.  You either need to preload images, or load them in another task that then updates the image property when it completes

Comment: I would have no idea how to do that

Comment: the simplest approach would be to loop through your list or users and call `GetImage` on each one, and then assign it to your ItemsSource